# How to pass multiple functions with multiple arguments using purr::map?

Tags: r

I'm trying to evaluate multiple functions on my dataset using purr library. I tried spliting the data and then apply map with the functions list but I don't seem to find the right way to introduce my varaibles as arguments. What I am missing?

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(f1 = c('a','a','a','b','b','c','c','c','d','d'),
       f2 = c('z','x','y','z','x','z','x','y','z','x'),
       obs = sample(1:10, 10),
       pred = sample(1:10,10))
#RMSE
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
rmse <- function(obs, model){
  n = length(obs)
  diff = (model - obs)**2
  rmse = sqrt(sum(diff)) / n
  return(rmse)
}
#Mean Bias
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
mean_bias <- function(obs, model){
  n =length(obs)
  diff=model-obs
  mean_bias=sum(diff)/n
  return(mean_bias)
}
#Mean error
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
mean_error <- function(obs, model){
  n =length(obs)
  abs=abs(model-obs)
  mean_error=sum(abs)/n
  return(mean_error)
}

mod_eval <- list(rmse, mean_bias,mean_error)


test <- df%>%
        split(list(c(.$f1,.$f2)))%>%
        invoke_map(.f=mod_eval)##????
```

I'll expect to get something like this

```
  f1 f2 rmse mean_bias mean_error
1  a  x   17        11          5
2  b  x   17        11          5
3  c  x   17        11          5
4  d  x   17        11          5
5  a  y   17        11          5
6  b  y   17        11          5
```

Comment: So what exactly is your desired output here? How would you create what you want without using purrr (aka "the long way") for this simple example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a named list of functions and use `map` to apply each function to each combination.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

mod_eval <- lst(rmse, mean_bias,mean_error)

df %>%
  split(.$f1) %>%
  map_df(function(x) map_dbl(mod_eval, ~.x(x$obs, x$pred)), .id = 'f1')

#  f1     rmse mean_bias mean_error
#  <chr> <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>
#1 a      2.33     -1.67       3.67
#2 b      3.91      5.5        5.5 
#3 c      2.92     -2.33       4.33
#4 d      2.5       0.5        3.5
```

Comment: Will this work using two factors  in the split function? I tried using .id=c('f1', 'f2') but it wont work.

Comment: You need to `split(list(.$f1, .$f2))` and `id=c('f1', 'f2')` won't work. Keep it as it is `.id = 'f1'` and then separate the `f1` column into two splitting on `'.'` using `separate`.

Answer (score 1):

We could use `tidyverse` approaches

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

mod_eval <- dplyr::lst(rmse, mean_bias, mean_error)
df %>%
     nest_by(f1) %>%
     crossing(mod_eval) %>%
     mutate(nm1 = names(mod_eval)) %>%
     rowwise %>% 
    transmute(f1, nm1, out = list(mod_eval(data$obs, data$pred))) %>%
    unnest(out) %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from = nm1, values_from = out)
```

-output

```
  f1     rmse mean_bias mean_error
  <chr> <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>
1 a      1.80     0.333       3   
2 b      3.35    -1.5         4.5 
3 c      3.09     4           4.67
4 d      4.53    -5           5
```

---

if it is grouped by 'f1', 'f2'

```
df %>%
     nest_by(f1, f2) %>%
     crossing(mod_eval) %>%
     mutate(nm1 = names(mod_eval)) %>%
     rowwise %>% 
    transmute(f1, f2, nm1, out = list(mod_eval(data$obs, data$pred))) %>%
    unnest(out) %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from = nm1, values_from = out)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 10 x 5
   f1    f2     rmse mean_bias mean_error
   <chr> <chr> <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>
 1 a     x         4        -4          4
 2 a     y         2         2          2
 3 a     z         3         3          3
 4 b     x         3         3          3
 5 b     z         6        -6          6
 6 c     x         1        -1          1
 7 c     y         7         7          7
 8 c     z         6         6          6
 9 d     x         9        -9          9
10 d     z         1        -1          1
```

Comment: Thanks akrun, this is really similar to what I had before and a good approach to answer the general problem. I am just trying to get my head around the map functions.

Comment: @Jhonathan one issue in the code is the `split` it should be a `list` i.e. `df%>%
        split(f= .[c('f1', 'f2')], drop = TRUE)`